# How to set a cookie apart from a session

Tags: php, session, cookies

I am running a login script which sets a session with the `user_id` and it works perfect. But I also want to set a cookie if the user checks the remember me checkbox which I assigned a variable to it `$remember = $_POST['remember'];` but the cookie isn't set. If I check the remember me box, it only starts the session, but when I exit my browser and come back, I have to login again which shows that the cookie isn't set. Now I stored the session with the `user_id` and the cookie with the `user_name`. I don't think the html part is relevant and my login validation from the database because they work perfect and all variables are been assigned so here is the code that sets the session and cookie:

```
        if($password == $pass_word){
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
            if($remember == "on"){
                setcookie("user_name", $user_name, time()+2592000);
            }               
        }
```

And this is my `loggedin()` function:

```
function loggedin(){
    if((isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) || ((isset($_COOKIE['user_name'])) && (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])))){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

but it only sets the session without the cookie. Please what am I getting wrong.

Comment: Can you please clarify: Does the cookie actually not get set (is not in the http headers / not stored in the browser), or do you only not get logged in again? I suspect the latter, because your condition looks kind of funky

Comment: Is `if($password == $pass_word){` the top of the file? If not edit the post and add the rest above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it. The `cookie` was set but I have to restart the `session` if the browser has been closed so this is my solution

```
// db connection here
function loggedin(){
    if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']){
        return true;
    } else if(isset($_COOKIE['user_name']){
        $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id FROM users WHERE user_name='". $_COOKIE['user_name']."'");
        $sql = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $sql['id'];
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```